# Upload photo to Dropbox by Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am developing an android application to upload photo to dropbox..I can upload photo to facebook and twitter by using facebook sdk and twitter4j but i don't know  how to upload photos to dropbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go..it uploads all kinds of files..

```
    String outPath = "/mnt/sdcard/" + filename;
    File outFile = new File(outPath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(outFile);
    mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest("/"+filename, fis, outFile.length(),null);
```

mApi is DropboxAPI object.

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox developer pages](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) has extensive information.

For Android, you can read the detail, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#android). And for [REST API references](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api). Particularly, the [File POST](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-POST) section.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is now deprecated (v1 of the library).

[Here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#dropbox-for-java-tutorial) you can follow an example using the current API. Keep in mind that this API is for Java in general, there is no official SDK for Android. What you have to consider, being Android, is to place all the network-related operations in another thread (apart from the UI thread). Typically, the best way to go is using a Service (since uploading images can take a really long time).